# Regarding implemenation of a scenario

Tags: eclipse

I have condition which states that..In additon to this WalgreensRewardsDRLookupEnabledPPI class  should check if  the
field  WAG_REWARDS_DR_ROLLOUT_LOOKUP_ LOCKED is true.  If it is true, then check the transaction parameter
ITransactionHashtableWag.EMPLOYEE_DISCOUNT_APPLIED_ENABLE_LOOKUP. Only when it
is true, return with value 10 otherwise return with value 0.If  WAG_REWARDS_DR_ROLLOUT_LOOKUP_ LOCKED  is false, simply return with 10.

please advise is the below implementation in terms of code is correct or not..

```
    if (WAG_REWARDS_DR_ROLLOUT_LOOKUP_ LOCKED == true)
{
   if ( (WAG_REWARDS_DR_ROLLOUT_LOOKUP_ LOCKED == true) && (ITransactionHashtableWag.EMPLOYEE_DISCOUNT_APPLIED_ENABLE_LOOKUP == true)
    {
  return 10 ;

}
}
else 
return 0;
```

Please advise is the above implementation is correct .!!

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct. You have no return statement for when WAG_REWARDS_DR_ROLLOUT_LOOKUP_LOCKED is true and EMPLOYEE_DISCOUNT_APPLIED_ENABLE_LOOKUP is false.
You can greatly simplify this to:

```
if (WAG_REWARDS_DR_ROLLOUT_LOOKUP_LOCKED
    && ITransactionHashtableWag.EMPLOYEE_DISCOUNT_APPLIED_ENABLE_LOOKUP) {
  return 10;
}
return 0;
```